# How do I view an Outlook .msg file?

Tags: file-format, microsoft-office

I need to view a .msg file.  It is an email from Microsoft Outlook.  How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/282691/how-to-convert-msg-file-outlook-email-msg-into-eml

Comment: At least with Thunderbird(45.8.0)->Open File it displays somewhat readable.

Comment: check this Answer for this issue: https://superuser.com/a/1472788/880537

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like the best thing to do is to convert them to an eml file using this script:

http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/

It's not pretty, it's not gui based, but it'll work.

Comment: After installing the script as indicated (cpan -i Email::Outlook::Message) found a quick way to call it: creating a "Nautilus Script" with: #!/bin/bash
for arg do
 msgconvert "$arg"
done

Comment: I can install this on my computer with `sudo apt install libemail-outlook-message-perl` and then just `msgconvert xyz.msg` and I get a `xyz.eml` file

Comment: Today the latest version is v0.920 and it still turns HTML messages into plain text messages

Answer (score 43):

Building on Martin Owens answer, this is the quick solution:

```
wget http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/msgconvert.pl
sudo apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl libemail-localdelivery-perl libemail-sender-perl
perl msgconvert.pl YourMessage.msg
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 I also needed this package: `libemail-sender-perl`

Answer (score 23):

I am on Ubuntu 15.10 and matijs'es msgconvert script seems to be available in the repos now. after running:

`sudo apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl libemail-localdelivery-perl libemail-sender-perl`

I can now now run

`msgconvert *.msg`

to convert the messages entirely with tools from the repos.

Answer (score 21):

Open it with MsgViewer http://sourceforge.net/projects/msgviewer/

```
wget -O MSGViewer.zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/msgviewer/files/latest/download
unzip MSGViewer.zip
cd MSGViewer-1.9
java -jar MSGViewer.jar
```

now, just drag'n'drop the msg file to the program window to have its contents displayed.

Comment: MSGViewer is a nice program, but I found that the viewer wouldn't open an attached .PDF file within the .MSG file. It appeared to change the filename to something that it couldn't find.

Comment: This works nicely. However I have some problems with the encoding of non ASCI mails (in my case Greek).  Do you happen to know if there is any setting for this.

Comment: This works with Java 8. Java 11, that I tried with first, removed the java activation framework this uses and so no longer works without some extra effort to use the replacement https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf

Comment: Opening attached files (e.g. PDF files) worked fine for me after changing the `OpenCommand` from `kde-open` to `xdg-open` (MSGViewer setting).

Answer (score 4):

I found after install msgconvert that msgconvert wasn't installed when I ran the command. Rather than faff about trying to debug it, I did this. Done in less than a minute. http://www.zamzar.com/convert/msg-to-pdf/

Comment: it doesnt handle attachments, so it's pretty fail imo

Comment: I converted from .MSG to .EML, and the attachments come through correctly. The .EML files was openable with Thunderbird.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *ruby-msg* ruby gem for that purposes. So:

1. Install ruby and rubygems:

   ```
   # apt-get install rubygems gem
   ```
2. Install the gem:

   ```
   # gem install ruby-msg
   ```
3. Then use the "mapitool" utility:

   ```
   $ mapitool -i test.msg
   ```

   In some cases you can sporadically get the exception:

   ```
   /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ruby-msg-1.5.2/lib/mapi/mime.rb:109:in `join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
   ```

   So just fix the following file **lib/mapi/mime.rb** with the following regexp:

   ```
   sed 's/part.to_s(opts)/part.to_s(opts).encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "")/' -i /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ruby-msg-1.5.2/lib/mapi/mime.rb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With SeaMonkey program,
Link please see below:
http://www.seamonkey-project.org/

Comment: Where do you see that seamonkey is able to view those files? Add a detailed description please.

Comment: Please install this program, after that from "File" menu choose "open file..." and choose your .msg file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an online viewer such as:

https://msgeml.com

It displays the .msg message, provides download links for the attachments, shows the headers, and converts the file to .eml.