# How can I convert .msg files (Outlook email message) into .eml?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have just started using Ubuntu & Thunderbird.

I have saved my Outlook emails in my hard disk and they have an `.msg` extension. Now when I try to open them in Thunderbird it doesn't open them because Thunderbird used `.eml` extension.

Please advise how I can convert my old emails from Outlook into Thunderbird format.

Comment: There's an online converter here: https://www.jitbit.com/msg2eml/ (disclaimer: I'm one of the coders who created this free tool)

Comment: similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24884/how-do-i-view-an-outlook-msg-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view an Outlook .msg file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24884/how-do-i-view-an-outlook-msg-file)

Answer (score 12):

Install the following modules:

```
sudo apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl libemail-localdelivery-perl
```

When installed, download the `.pl` file named [`msgconvert.pl`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvz/msgconvert/master/script/msgconvert.pl), then run:

```
./msgconvert.pl --mbox [desiredFilename].eml [currentFileName].msg
```

Now you can open your `.eml` file in thunderbird.

**Reference**:

---

- [Kosala's - Blog: Convert Outlook .msg to Thunderbird .eml](http://kosalads.blogspot.nl/2012/11/how-to-convert-outlook-msg-to.html)
- [`libemail-outlook-message-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libemail-outlook-message-perl)
- [`libemail-localdelivery-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libemail-localdelivery-perl)
- [Virustotal report for msgconvert.pl](https://www.virustotal.com/nl/file/c435b5555c42a731ff6c26bb02d47e80211184cf0a7c3ce420e6db135244dbc5/analysis/1387895460/)

Comment: msgconvert.pl is not available for public access

Comment: @Ilja , can't seem to contact the original author(source part in my A).

Comment: I think to download msgconvert.pl manually is not a good way. Better use system tools from Perl: `sudo cpan -i Email::Outlook::Message`

Comment: Echoing @JaimeM., I think future visitors would be best served by [`msgconvert.pl`'s author's blog post](http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/), his [github](https://github.com/mvz/msgconvert), or the [official Perl stuff his script became](https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl).

Comment: mirrored `msgconvert.pl` @ https://transfer.sh/11eA5j/msgconvert.pl

Comment: Opening that Google Docs link in private browsing, I get a 403 no authorization error. I'm replacing it with the link to the raw Github file instead from @Michael's comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is a online tool to convert mail files into different formats, eml included: 
[Online Mail Converter](http://www.coolutils.com/Online-Mail-Converter.php)

Comment: Good to know but this is not suitable for many purposes such as emails containing private or sensitive company information.

Answer (score -2):

Just save the mail in .txt format and change the extension to .eml

Saw it here and it works: [Super User - How to save a mail into an .eml-file with Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/75581/how-to-save-a-mail-into-an-eml-file-with-outlook)

The most funny is that there are proprietary converter for that!

Comment: Saving as `.txt` doesn't preserve the entire message headers and attachments. it's just the body and basic headers and isn't `.eml` format.